# Postman request encoding

Tags: java, kotlin, postman

I'm writing my own HTTP server. I'm using `Java Socket` for it. I read request from `InputStream` next way

```
val input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.inputStream, "UTF-8"))
```

When I receive requests from `curl` or browser all is good. But when I receive request from `Postman` I get something like this:

```
��g�������#���=��g�������#���, ��9� ��3���5�/�=��9� ��3���5�/�,
```

I tried to use others encodings for `InputStreamReader` such as `UTF-16` and `ASCII`. Which encoding is used for Postman requests and how I can read it on my server?

***UPDATE:*** Sorry, this is my failure. I used HTTPS when making requests.

Comment: Be prepared for the question "why would anyone write their own HTTP server when they could use one of the hundred libraries for Java instead?" question.

Comment: Can you say what the first few bytes are as numbers?

Comment: Can you share the HTTP headers sent by Postman to the server?

Comment: You didn't say what "receive" means, HTTP POST, HTTP GET, is this being received during or after content negotiation, etc.

Comment: Maybe Postman is sending cookie data?  Is this HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Did you try using one of the other HTTP libraries or other server that can echo the requests send from postman?  Try: http://request.urih.com/ from postman.

Comment: Are you in the legacy chrome extension of Postman, or the separate full packaged version?

Answer (score 2):

If the first two bytes received are ASCII 31 (0x1F) and 139 (0x8B) you are receiving a GZIP stream and for some reason convinced the client that you supported GZIP `Content-Encoding` (not the same thing as the charset encoding).

The data looks more binary than character encoding.  Gzip, deflate, SSL, or other reason for binary data is what should be looked at.

You may not be doing content negotiation correctly and therefore receiving binary gzip or deflate. Or using HTTPS vs. HTTP.  Or uploading an image.  Something but not text.

Answer (score 1):

***NOTE:*** my other answer is more direct, this is related HTTP server libraries for use in Kotlin, in case others read this question and want to know alternatives.  Not sure if this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and if the author is not aware of other options.

Other ways if you do not want to build an HTTP library, but instead use one:

**Raw HTTP frameworks:**

- Anything written for Java, and specifically:
- [Undertow.io](http://undertow.io/)
- [Vert.x 3](http://vertx.io/docs/) with [Vert.x-web](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/)
- [Netty](http://netty.io/) - very low level

**Somewhat more than raw HTTP, but not a MVC or REST framework:**

- [Wasabi](https://github.com/hhariri/wasabi) - Kotlin specific

**And for fuller REST or Web frameworks:**

- [KTOR](https://github.com/Kotlin/ktor) - Kotlin specific
- [Kovert](https://github.com/kohesive/kovert) - Kotlin specific, REST but adding views (*Disclaimer: I'm the author*)
- [Spark Java](http://sparkjava.com/) - Java, works nicely in Kotlin
- [Vert.x Nubes](https://github.com/aesteve/nubes) - Java, to work on top of Vert.x
- [Kikaha](http://kikaha.skullabs.io/) - Java, to work on top of Undertow